# Making list from DB::select in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've been trying to get some raw queries working in laravel 4.2. I've reduce the query to the following for testing. Making a list of the results doesn't work:

```
$latest_exams = DB::select("SELECT * from tb_exams where id = '21953120'");
$latest_exams_ids = $latest_exams->lists('id');
```

The final query has a number of exams and I'd like to end up with an array of the ids of those exams. 
Any ideas or suggestions?

edit: to clarify, it appears that it's the creation of the list that causes the error.  this simplified query works fine. i am able to dump the result to the page and it's as expected.   When I add the "lists" line, it breaks. I included the query in case that has something to do with the list not working.

Comment: the query will return just one exam if exist !!

Comment: In addition to my previous comment do jast like that `$latest_exams = DB::select("SELECT * from tb_exams)->get();` and don't forget **->get()** :)

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear.  For some reason, it appears to be the making of the list that is broken.  The query is fine and is a simplified version of the "real" one, which is complex, in order to remove its complexity as a possible issue.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `$latest_exams = DB::select("SELECT * from tb_exams where id = '21953120'");`
Which will return only one result

```
where id = 21953120
```

First I'd advice you use Eloquent query builder (Use your model rather than writing SQL query by yourself)

```
$latest_exams = ModelName::all();
```

Will return an array of all exams.
If you still go with your previous SQL query then remove the `where` condition to get all the exam as an array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.   I have an Exam model. I have this query as an example of how I'm doing it. The SELECT that I have here is a very simplified query.  The final query is a complex one trying to get MAX dates, group by, and other things. I'm using this simplified query because there isn't any reason this should break. It grabs one exam, so that I could eliminate the complex query as the issue.   It's the "$latest_exams_ids = $latest_exams->lists('id');" that appears to be breaking things.

Comment: Hi, @Kevin could you ascertain the result of $latest_exams? afaik, [it should be an array](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Connection.html#method_select).. which i have doubts whether it had function at all.. try to post your error or `dd($latest_exams)`. Sorry, but i rarely use `DB::Select()`.

Answer (score 1):

To add some flavours to the answer, i decided to write my own. As Michel mentioned, you could make a [model](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) for the table instance and query through the Eloquent query builder. For unrestricted query you could use [all](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_all) method in the model.

`$latest_exams = ModelName::all('id');`

Alternatively, you could keep your raw sql this way as per [doc described](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#running-queries):

`$latest_exams = DB::select("select id from from tb_exams");`

remember to only select the id.
I bet you're maintaining some old projects (Laravel now hits version 5.3).. tbh, read the docs first, dig it up to the api documentation or even the source itself. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Like I mentioned in reply to Michel.  The query is a simplified version to eliminate its complexity as the source of the issue.  But i wanted to keep the same "type" of query, i.e. a raw sql query.